# How do I get all images within Wordpress Uploads directory, then display all?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to get all of the images inside a specific sub-directory within the `Wordpress` `uploads` directory, and then output all of those images.

```
$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir(); 
$logo_dir = ( $upload_dir['baseurl'] . '/logos/' );
echo $logo_dir . '-----<br />';
$images = glob($logo_dir . "*.PNG");
foreach($images as $image)
{
   echo $image;
}
```

`$logo_dir` is outputting the correct directory. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong with the `foreach`.

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: have you tried `*.png` (lowercase) ?

Comment: @PedroLobito thanks for your help. I did try lowercase. I've got it set to uppercase since all of the files in the directory are automatically generated and always have the extension in uppercase (not sure if that matters)

Comment: What's the path of `$logo_dir` ?

Comment: @PedroLobito 
             `http://petersburg3.prairiemarketinginc.com/wp-content/uploads/logos/`

Comment: it should be something like `/petersburg3.prairiemarketinginc.com/wp-content/uploads/logos/` or `/home/petersburg3.prairiemarketinginc.com/wp-content/uploads/logos/` notice the opening and closing  `/`.

Comment: You're posting an `url` and you need to use the **local path** with `glob`, something like `/home/user/..../`

Comment: @PedroLobito Thank you!!! I was using the baseurl of wp_upload_dir(); when I needed to be using basedir for the path. My eyes overlooked that. All fixed now.

Comment: I just figure out that. I've update my answer. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_upload_dir

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked out.

Comment: @PedroLobito do you know how I can make this work to display the images? I changed it to this:

`echo '<img src="' . $image . '" />';`

but the local path doesnt work as an img src

Comment: for that you can use `basename` to get the filename and then `$upload_dir['baseurl']."/$image"` . I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
$logo_dir = ( $upload_dir['baseurl'] . '/logos/' );
```

to

```
$logo_dir = ( $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/logos/' );
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_upload_dir

---

**Update** based on your comments:

```
foreach($images as $image)
{
$filename = basename($image);
echo $upload_dir['baseurl']."/$filename";
}
```