# How do I open imgs file located in another directory on my server?

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, directory, wordpress-theming

I'm quite new at Stackoverflow, PHP, and WP themes making and I'm facing the following problem: I'm developing an image carousel on the homepage of the blog (located in `home.php` in the theme directory) but I need to retrieve the images on a different directory (`/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/HP/carousel`) because, for final user sake, I'm using Max Foundry's Wordpress Media Library Folders (https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/media-library-plus/) making a specific folder for the carousel in order to simplify the process of uploading the carousel for the final users.

I tried PHP functions `opendir()` or `scandir()` together with `glob()` and it works IF the directory is inside the same one of the theme directory, but my client should then use something like FTP and Filezilla, and I don't want him to let him play with tool that potentially can destroy my work. So I looked for an alternative solution on the web: I found out I should use something like `ABSPATH` or idk, not working at all, it doesn't recognize the string as a path. I also tried with WP function `get_site_url()` that is working for a similar purpose in another section of the page, but here it doesn't work.

```
$dir = get_site_url().'/wp-content/uploads/HP/carousel/';

if (is_dir($dir)) //testing if it's a directory
  printf($dir);
else {
  echo 'not a directory';
}
```

same result using `ABSPATH`. Then obviusly if I try to open the directory with opendir it returns an error.

I am still learning and I can't find a good reference that explains how this functions and global variable work so I guess something is missing to me.
I want my code to open another directory, that is local because it's on the same server, from another, specifically the directory in which I'm building my theme.
Really thank you for your time and eventual help.

**edit:** Thank you @cptnk and @Uri Chachick, I didn't know about the function `wp_upload_dir()` and now the path is recognized as a directory, but if I try to read its content with `opendir()`, `scandir()` or `glob()` the array in which I am putting - I guess - the content result to be empty when trying to print it. I thought the problem came from the formatting of the string with both `\` and `/` in it, so I turned all backslashes into forward slashes, but still nothing, I can't retrieve the images inside the directory (that now it's correctly reached). How can I have access to the images?

Comment: get_site_url is not what you should be using to begin with - because that is for _URLs_, not _file system_ paths. If you are not aware of that difference, go read up on/figure that out first of all.

Comment: Secondly, give us a proper problem description - not just “doesn’t work”. [ask]. Make a debug output of $dir, and see if that contains what you expected it to - or what else, if not.

Comment: @misorude Tank you for your comment, I thought the "doesn't work" thing was clear as other users undestood it, but I'm gonna edit my question to make it clearer. With "doesn't work" I meant I can't reach the directory I am looking for (paragraph 2 line 5). I also know that get_site_url() is for URLs, as the function name says, I meant I tryed both using a URL and file system path to open the directory but I don't know how to do it properly because what I meant to do didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

you can use wp_upload_dir() like this:

```
$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
$dir = $upload_dir['basedir'].'/HP/carousel/';

if(is_dir($dir))  //testing if it's a directory
    printf($dir);
else {
    echo 'not a directory';
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I updated the question resolving half of the issue, give a look at it please.

Comment: I tried and found no problem using "scandir" to list the files in a directory. can you paste youre entire code including the scandir part?

Comment: Sorry for the lateness, I finally solved the problem by using custom posts as suggested. Thank you very much, I appreciate your try to help me

Answer (score 0):

I personally never used media library+ but to my understanding it only enhances the wordpress backend functionality and you still interact with the attachments the same way you'd normally would.

Meaning that you can still use functions like https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url and retrieve the attachment url after querying for it.

If your code requires you to find the actual path you can also use https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_upload_dir/

EDIT: I think I now get what you are actually trying to achieve or where the problem lays. I think you have a misconception as to what a URL and a PATH is.

A **URL**(Uniform Resource Locator) does not represent your Filesystem it is used to serve Resources (html, css, js, img...) via the Web server (nginx, apache...).

A **PATH** represents the current location on **your** machine (C:\Users\you\pictures, /home/pictures...)

The **server** is usually only aware of paths and how to "map" them together. You as the **client** should never be able to see file paths and only URL's. That is why wordpress methods like wp_upload_dir and wp_get_attachment_url exists so you don't have to manually translate PATH's to URL's before you render the HTML.

Now you probably want retrieve the images from the folder the plugin created for you(stack overflow answer: [How do I get all images within Wordpress Uploads directory, then display all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33060580/how-do-i-get-all-images-within-wordpress-uploads-directory-then-display-all))

I personally dislike this approach for several reasons and most people would probably create a custom post type or use Plugins like ACF with the option page functionality (https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/options-page/) to persist information.

Comment: Thank you, I updated the question resolving half of the issue, give a look at it please.